# How to extract the values of the alt atributte within img with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, getattribute

I have the following problem, I haven't been able to solve it.
I have to extract the text that appears in an `alt` attribute of an image. The `id` always changes, as does the contained `alt`.

[image: Example]

I noticed that the `id` only changes in this part

```
//*[@id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:**2**:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:**2**:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"]
//*[@id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:**1**:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:**1**:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"]
//*[@id="j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:**0**:j_id1102997597_32d04d7a:**0**:j_id1102997597_32d04d8e:j_id415163359_4cfbfc60"]
```

Anyway, I am still unable to log in.

Comment: //*[contains(@id,'')] then use .get_attribute('alt')

Comment: Hi @ArundeepChohan it is correct ? 
Imagen = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*contains(@id,'j_id1102997597_32d04ef7:0:j_id1102997597_32d04d36:')]").get_attribute('alt')

Comment: can you share url of the page?

Comment: Yes, but it is in spanish 
https://www.santander.cl/cotizador-web/

Comment: in that case, can you post screenshot of the element you want to extract

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrJmu.png

I want to extract alt text

Comment: I don't see this element on this exact page https://www.santander.cl/cotizador-web/

Comment: Do I need to click on some element for it to load?

Comment: Yes, you have to fill in all these data, otherwise, the table with the images does not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract and print the values of the ***alt*** attribute you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("alt") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.matriz table > tbody tr.filaMatriz > td > img[alt]")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("alt") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='matriz']//table/tbody//tr[@class='filaMatriz']/td/img[@alt]")))])
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup for this (install with `pip install bs4`):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')

images = soup.select_one('div.text-center').select('img')

for image in images:
print(image.get('alt'))
```